# Postmaster error with Mandrill App

Tags: postmaster, profile-edit

I am using Profile:Edit to register new members, then using Postmaster to trigger emails when they have registered and been approved.

I am currently having a problem with Postmaster when I use the "screen_name" field when registering in Profile:Edit. I receive this error.

```
Error

Mandrill Service - Error: The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error
history.go(-1);”]« Back
```

Even though I am getting this error, the member still registered to the site, but the Postmaster email is not triggered. But if I remove screen_name in the registration form the member is registered and an email is triggered.

I have right now username, screen name, and email all as the email address of the registered member, and would like to add some uniqueness to screen_name.

Has anyone come into an error like this using postmaster?

Answer (score 0):

I get these errors in mandrill when there is a tag instead of an email address.

Comment: Can you elaborate further to help answer the question better please?